# Version assets with folders?

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

I have a folder with various sub folders and files:

```
- images
   -products
       - product-1.jpg
   -users
       - user-1.jpg
       - user-2.jpg
   -test.jpg
```

How can I version all of the assets?

```
mix.version('public/img/');
```

The above only does the top level.

Comment: Have you tried `'public/img/**/*'`?

Comment: Yep - that does not work, just gives empty folders.

Comment: A simple `mix.version()` should do the trick, because it versions all of the assets compiled by laravel mix

Comment: Nope - that does not work either.

Comment: You do need to 'compile' assets you want to version with `mix`, you can't just put files inside `images` folder manually and hope `mix` will version them

Comment: If the images are being referenced by relative paths in your sass files it will happen automatically: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#url-processing but otherwise you'll need to add a plugin: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/laravel-mix-image-workflow